# What could be Regex for reading first line of file with first few bytes and then rest of file content except last 8 bytes of last line of file?

Tags: ruby, regex, file, byte

I am processing one binary file in which I want to retrieve first 4 bytes, next 4 bytes, again 4 bytes and then rest of the file contents except last 8 bytes of last line.

I have tried with this line `file.read.scan(/(.{4})(.{4})(.{4})(.*\w)(.{8})/).each do |a,b,c,d,e|` but after some iterations this regex starts from some line in between with first 4 bytes, next 4 bytes, next 4 bytes pattern. Because of this my condition check fails.

I want to do following.
Read first 4 bytes of first line of file, then bytes 5 to 7, then bytes 8 to 11, then rest of the file content except last 8 bytes of last line of the file.

What could be the regex for this in Ruby?

Comment: You should go back and accept some answers on your old questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
/(.{4})(.{3})(.{4})(.*).{8}/m
```

Answer (score 2):

Use #read instead of a regexp:

```
f = File.open(file_name,"rb")
chunk1 = f.read(4)
chunk2 = f.read(3)
chunk3 = f.read(4)
chunk4 = f.read(f.size - (4 + 3 + 4 + 8))
```